# Docker-Compose up Failed Because `Service 'nginx' failed to build`

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm new to docker, and have been trying to troubleshoot this error for a while. I've read similar posts and nothing seems to work.

**Full error:**

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: could not fetch content descriptor sha256:eff196a3849ad6541fd3afe676113896be214753740e567575bb562986bd2cd4 (application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+json) from remote: not found
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build : Build failed 
I have three Dockerfiles, one for my react frontend, one for my django backend, and one for nginx.
```

**Frontend dockerfile:**

```
COPY ./react_app/package.json .
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
        python \
        make \
        g++ \
    && npm install \
    && apk del .gyp

COPY ./react_app .

ARG API_SERVER
ENV REACT_APP_API_SERVER=${API_SERVER}
RUN REACT_APP_API_SERVER=${API_SERVER} \ 
  npm run build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install -g serve
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build ./build
Django Python backend Dockerfile


WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.7.9-slim-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends netcat && \
   apt-get autoremove -y && \
   apt-get clean && \
   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY ./django_app .

RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
and the nginx dockerfile


FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

**Backend Dockerfile**

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7.9-slim-stretch as builder

# set work directory 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables 
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7.9-slim-stretch

# installing netcat (nc) since we are using that to listen to postgres server in entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends netcat && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install dependencies
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# copy our django project
COPY ./django_app .

# run entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Nginx Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

I don't know where to go from here. I've tried following 5 or 6 similar stack overflows and many more github issues, to no avail. Thanks, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the `FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine` with `FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine-perl` and it worked